# Neural network - curve of training and validation errors?

Tags: python, validation, machine-learning, neural-network, curve-fitting

The curve of this image represents what? Overfitting? Or that I can train for more epochs?

[image]

Comment: What do the ```axes``` represent?

Comment: IMO, it doesn't seem to overfit because your ```val_loss``` is also decreasing. That means the model is not that bad for the held out set. Also, you could see the accuracy curves of both. If you see a huge gap between ```train``` and ```val``` accuracy, it is generally an indication of poor generalization due to overfitting.

Comment: y-axis = error, x-axis = number of epochs

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question.